# Problem with position: fixed, div is not really where it should be

Tags: css, xhtml

THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED: I specified `right: 0px` instead of `top: 0px`...

I have a problem with CSS' `position: fixed;` both in Firefox (6.0.2), Chromium (12.0.742.112) and Konqueror (4.6.2). Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <div style="background: grey; position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="margin: 50px;">
      test
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My aim is that the first `<div>` is concealing the whole viewport, but in all three browsers, it does not occludes the topmost 50+x pixels -- which is exactly the top margin of the second `<div>`. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how I can fix this without dirty hacks?

Note that inserting any text between the first and the second `<div>` decreases the problem in the sense that only the topmost x picels are not occluded, which also can be removed by adding `style="margin: 0px;"` to the `<body>` tag. The result of the above sample code as well as the version with an "x" added between the two `<div>`'s in Konqueror can be seen 
here: [image: Example in Konqueror]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Don't bother to edit your question to say "the problem is solved." Either mark the answer as accepted, or just delete the question. I recommend the latter.

Comment: I had to wait for a certain time (8 minutes) before I could accept your answer. But thanks for the hint, I'll delete the question. (And thanks again for the answer!)

Comment: (I cannot delete the question since there are answers...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified `top: 0` on the fixed-position div. Why not?

Comment: Oh. Oooops. The `right: 0px` should have been `top: 0px`. I'm really sorry and feel quite stupid now...